# How to set behaviour for AngularJS filter for non-valid data?

Tags: angularjs

Imagine that I have a filter in AngularJS (let's say date or currency filter) and want to make the following: if value for the filtering is a valid one (it has valid date of valid currency format) - apply filter, otherwise just output the initial value instead of a filtered. Is there any standard way to implement such behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: create a method on scope .. put logic there then call from view .

Comment: You can write your own custom filter.